# upload an excel file and read the data

Tags: python

**In my application, I uploaded an excel file and trying to read the data.
I am trying in following way,**

```
@expose()
def save(self, **params):
    xls_file = params['xls_file']
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(bill_file,'w')
    sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
    for i,rownum in enumerate(range(sh.nrows)):
        print sh.row_values(rownum)
```

**But getting the following errors:**

**TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, instance found**

Module xlrd:425 in open_workbook         view
<<          encoding_override=encoding_override,
               formatting_info=formatting_info,
               on_demand=on_demand,
               )
           t1 = time.clock()

> > on_demand=on_demand,
> >     Module xlrd:878 in biff2_8_load         view
> >     <<              retry = False
> >                        try:
> >                            f = open(filename, open_mode)
> >                        except IOError:
> >                            e, v = sys.exc_info()[:2]
> >      f = open(filename, open_mode)

Comment: why `range` **and** `enumerate`? You get same values `0, 1, 2...` both for i and rownum.

Answer (score 0):

enumerate() is already returning pairs (index, item). The range() call is completely unnecessary.